# JQuery, swap image smoothly

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with changing image. It changes, but not smoothly. I need exactly jquery, not css approach, because I need to change img attribute.

My attempt

```
$("#klubnika").hover(function() {
  $("#klubnika").attr("src","img/team-section/banka-klub.jpg");
    },function() {
      $("#klubnika").attr("src","img/team-section/klubnika.jpg");
    }
);
```

Any ideas, how to make swap effect smoothly?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "smoothly"? Do you mean you want it to fade between the two?
Also, wouldn't it be better to use CSS3 with animations?

Comment: if your problem is that the new image loads when you swap, than load it to a tmp/invisible img tag first, and than swap them when it loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really would use two images for this and use this way:

```css
#klubnika {position: relative; display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;}
#klubnika img {display: block;}
#klubnika img.off {position: absolute; z-index: 1; left: 0; top: 0; opacity: 0; transition: opacity 0.5s linear;}
#klubnika:hover img.off {opacity: 1;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<div id="klubnika">
  <img src="//placehold.it/200x100?text=Hello" class="on" />
  <img src="//placehold.it/200x100?text=World" class="off" />
</div>
```

If you hate the CSS based approach for some reason, you can do it using `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` using jQuery and would recommend using **HTML5 Data Attributes** for scaling it:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#klubnika").hover(function () {
    $(this).find("img").fadeOut(function () {
      this.src = $(this).data("hover");
      $(this).fadeIn();
    });
  }, function () {
    $(this).find("img").fadeOut(function () {
      this.src = $(this).data("src");
      $(this).fadeIn();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<div id="klubnika">
  <img src="//placehold.it/200x100?text=Hello" data-src="//placehold.it/200x100?text=Hello" data-hover="//placehold.it/200x100?text=World" />
</div>
```

By scaling, I meant, you can have any number of images but one JavaScript code that makes it work across. See below:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".klubnika").hover(function () {
    $(this).find("img").fadeOut(function () {
      this.src = $(this).data("hover");
      $(this).fadeIn();
    });
  }, function () {
    $(this).find("img").fadeOut(function () {
      this.src = $(this).data("src");
      $(this).fadeIn();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<div class="klubnika">
  <img src="//placehold.it/200x100?text=Hello" data-src="//placehold.it/200x100?text=Hello" data-hover="//placehold.it/200x100?text=World" />
</div>
<div class="klubnika">
  <img src="//placehold.it/200x100?text=Another" data-src="//placehold.it/200x100?text=Another" data-hover="//placehold.it/200x100?text=Image" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery Animation for seamless image changes for example solution below

```
$("#klubnika").hover(function(){

   $(this).fadeOut('fast', function () {
       $(this).attr('src', "img/team-section/banka-klub.jpg");
       $(this).fadeIn('fast');
    }); 
});
```

Answered before Mentioned In

[jQuery animate on an image replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744579/jquery-animate-on-an-image-replacement?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Ha ha. That was quick.

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty much the same:
[Fading between images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605889/fading-between-images)

The answer they give there uses the fadeIn and fadeOut functions of jQuery like this:

```
<div id="imageSwap">
</div>  

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
      setImageOne();
    });

    function setImageOne() {
      $('#imageSwap').fadeIn(500).html('<img src="image01.jpg" />').delay(2000).fadeOut(500, function () { setImageTwo(); });
    }

    function setImageTwo() {
      $('#imageSwap').fadeIn(500).html('<img src="image02.jpg" />').delay(2000).fadeOut(500, function () { setImageOne(); });
    }

</script>
```

I think you can get the idea from this, but if possible, I recommend using CSS instead.